# Use of "an" for a word not starting with a vowel

Tags: articles, vowels, consonants

I've encountered this quite a few times now. I'm aware that usually words, starting with a vowel require an "an", words not starting with a vowel are preceded by an "a".

Sometimes words start with a consonant, but when spoken out loud, it sounds like a vowel, for instance *an hour*.

Is the use of "an" in this case correct due to the sound it would make when spoke out loud?

Comment: See [this question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6760/should-individual-letters-be-preceded-with-an), especially the accepted answer.

Comment: The accepted answer on [this question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/74859/some-words-starting-with-vowels-preceded-by-an-instead-or-a/74860#74860) explains it quite well, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the rule:

Use AN before words such as "hour" which sound like they start with a vowel even if the first letter is a consonant. Also use AN before letters and numbers which sound like they begin with a vowel, such as "F" or "8". Remember, it is the sound not the spelling which is important. For example, "F" is pronounced "eff" like it starts with an "E".

Examples:

I only have an hour for lunch. Sounds like "au-er".

Does his name begin with an "F"? Sounds like "eff"

Use A before words such as "European" or "university" which sound like they start with a consonant even if the first letter is a vowel. Also use A before letters and numbers which sound like they begin with a consonant, such as "U", "J", "1" or "9". Remember, it is the sound not the spelling which is important. For example, "1" is spelled O-N-E; however, it is pronounced "won" like it starts with a "W".

Examples:

She has a euro. Sounds like "yu-ro".

That number is a "1". Sounds like "won".

Comment: Which consonant "European" start sounds like?

Comment: @JoaoArruda "European" sounds like it starts with the consonant sound of a "y".

Comment: @JoaoArruda "Y", like "Your". (For added confusion, "Y" is sometimes a vowel... but not here.)

Comment: I guess it goes with the accent in which the word is spoken, in the case of "European"... I can see the "Y" now that you mentioned, but I couldn't before because it's not how I say it

Comment: @Joao.I hope you will find these tips helpful.

Comment: There's a childish joke that it sounds like "Your a-peein'".

Comment: @JustinYoung .Lol.!It can be used as a mnemonic!

Comment: That should be "you're"...bad native speaker...shame on me.

Comment: @JustinYoung .  :)