# Which one is correct: to enter an university or to enter the university

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

There is a sentence:
"When he was 16 he moved to London in order to enter ***the/an*** university"
Which article is more correct for this sentence ***the or an***?

Comment: There is a 3rd option 'to enter university'. *The* is a specific place, *a* is not specific (one of many), no article means he begins formal study as a phase of life, his 'career' as a student.

Comment: Welcome to ELL. Please visit the question I linked above. Also, it is ***a** university*, not ***an** university* because 'university' [starts with](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/74860/106592) a **consonant sound** (ignore the **vowel letter** 'u').

Comment: As a side note, "university" is pronounced like "you-niversity", so it would take "a" not "an".